# JavaScript boolean expression simplification

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, boolean

I got an interesting warning message from IntelliJ about some JavaScript code:

`((a === 'foo') || (a === 'bar')) ? true : false' can be simplified to '!!(((a === 'foo') || (a === 'bar')))`

I see why the structure `condition ? true : false` doesn't make sense, but shouldn't the condition itself represent a boolean value? So why should I use the double negation for the whole expression?

Comment: I assume you are asking why the IntelliJ produced such "simplification" suggestion?

Comment: I assume IntelliJ only recognizes the `cond ? true : false` part, but doesn't actually know what `cond` returns. That's why it adds `!!` as a precaution. But you are right, it is not necessary here.

Comment: Ask yourself this: Do you _really_ need it to be a boolean value that's returned? Isn't a "truthy" good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself this: Do you really need it to be a boolean value that's returned?

To answer your question: the reason IntelliJ suggests it, is because that's how it is configured.
It's just one of the ways you can have IntelliJ handle pointless conditionals.

In [the IntelliJ intentions documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/intentions.jsp), Look for: JavaScript --> Conditional Operator --> Remove Pointless Conditional.

A double boolean negation (`!!`) is a shorter, and arguably cleaner way of casting the result of the statement to a boolean value, instead of the `truthy` or `falsy` the statement normally returns.

Comment: We should be explicit **when we specifically want a boolean** and use `Boolean(a || b)`, leaving the `!!` trick to Uglifying libraries. Proof that `!!` is unclear at first sight is the fact that there is a [really popular question on Stack Overflow about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

You could test a Regular Expression: `/^foo$|^bar$/i.test(a)`. Now you don't need the ternary also.

`!!` converts the expression to a `Boolean`. It's to make sure you always get a `Boolean` from it. If you're certain the expression will deliver something '[truthy/falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)' I'd say you can do without the conversion. If you use the Regular Expression above the conversion is definitely not necessary.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: I'd rather see a `['foo', 'bar'].indexOf(a) !== -1` (or `includes` now) instead. A regexp is really hindering readability, even more so an inline regexp.